# Discord client Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Tags: python, discord, bots

On startup it should write a message in one of the text channels.

Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

```
channel = client.get_channel(111111111)   #I have the real id
message = ("Wow")
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=game)
    await channel.send(message)
```

Comment: which library are you using?

Comment: "I have a question" does not summarize the question at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`Bot` can get channel once it ready, that means before the bot is not ready you can't get a channel. And as you can see you are doing `get_channel()` before `on_ready()` event, i.e. Before the bot is ready.**

Get the channel in `on_ready` event and that should be good to go.

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=game) #game is not defined make sure to define it
    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
    await channel.send("Wow")
```

Comment: Thank you so much I was working with it 2 hours. Have a nice day :)

Comment: no problem, happy to help anytime. Mark answer as accepted so other people can know that its solved :)